# How do I create a shortcut link from the dock to an application?

Tags: macos, applications, dock, alias

I'm trying to put a link to Outlook Express in my dock but can't see how it's done. When I right-click on the application icon in a finder window, "Make Alias" is *not* one of the options available, so I can't make a shortcut and then move it down to the dock. If I drag the application icon itself down towards the dock it simply makes *another copy* of the entire application on the desktop. For some reason I *can* get a "Make Alias" option from this version (why would the right-click options be different depending on whether the same icon was in a finder window or on the desktop???). And I can then move the alias icon into the dock. But when I then delete the unneeded copy of the application on the desktop, the alias no longer works because it was linking to that copy rather than the original. I'm sure this must be simple but can I find any information on the Help files...?

I'm running OSX 10.6.8, so no I don't have a launchpad icon in the dock.

Answer (score 7):

For any app you want to add to your dock as a shortcut, the process is as follows:

1. Launch the application. The application's icon will appear in the dock.
2. Right click the application's icon in the dock.
3. Go to "Options".
4. Select "Keep in Dock".

Now the application's icon will remain in the dock as a shortcut when you quit the application.

Comment: You can also just drag the application from Finder to the Dock if it's not already running.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Dock is misbehaving. You should just be able to drag it.
Try going to Terminal (`/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`) and typing
`killall Dock`.

Then you should be able to drag the application straight in.